# How to only output one Pass/Fail result when test is rerun?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, reportng

I'm using the IRetryAnalyzer class in TestNG in order to relaunch tests that fail (up to 5 attempts).  Right now if I run a test and it fails three times before passing, it says:

> Tests run: 4, Failures: 3, Errors 0, Skipped 0.

What I want the results to show is:

> Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors 0, Skipped 0.

Basically, I don't want it to count as a failure unless it fails all 5 reruns. How do I do this?

Comment: Why is the test failing though ?

Answer (score 0):

since nobody replied, i give it a try.

just random thoughts i had when reading your post, while i was searching for a solution for my problem...

you can get the result of your test in your `@AfterTest` method via `ITestResult result`

```
@AfterMethod
public void AfterMethod_CheckForFailure(ITestResult result, Method m)
```

an `@AfterMethod` is called when a method with `@Test` annotation has finished.
able to read the current iteration from a `static` class with a `static` member
and if its `<5` then use

```
result.setStatus(ITestResult.SUCCESS); // or what ever status you want
setCurrentTestResult(result);
```

dunno if that works, but looks to me it could :) Good luck

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work. It seems NG is not designed for this - see Does this really work for you? It's not working with TestNG 6.8.8. And Cedric says that it's not meant or guaranteed to work: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/testng-users/J-kA6mD73i0/rc0vNTyygy0J

Answer (score 0):

I have just done this and how I did it was I considered everything before the last time a success. I did this to allow 3 reruns, here is the code I used:

```
import org.testng.IRetryAnalyzer;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.Reporter;

public class RetryAnalyzer implements IRetryAnalyzer {
  private int count = 0;
  private int maxCount = 2;

  @Override
  public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
    if (!result.isSuccess()) {
      if (count < maxCount) {
        count++;
        result.setStatus(ITestResult.SUCCESS);
        String message = Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": Error in " + result.getName() + " Retrying "
            + (maxCount + 1 - count) + " more times";
        System.out.println(message);
        Reporter.log(message);
        return true;
      } else {
        result.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

The key here was when I am still retrying, I set the result to success

```
result.setStatus(ITestResult.SUCCESS)
```

and when the attempt has been made and it still fails, then set it to a fail

```
result.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);
```

Comment: Does this really work for you? It's not working for me with TestNG 6.8.8. And Cedric says that it's not meant or guaranteed to work: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/testng-users/J-kA6mD73i0/rc0vNTyygy0J

Comment: @Fletch Honestly, I dont remember. I am not working on this, nor have access to it anymore. However, I do remember that I eventually threw this solution out the window. I can't remember why though. Sorry.

Comment: yeah I just went to JUnit - it has a better and easier way to do this.